# Compile OpenVswitch in Odroid XU4 has error

Tags: makefile, embedded-linux, openvswitch, odroid

I am doing OpenVswitch compile in Odroid XU4 with the kernel module.

I did execute the 'boot.sh' file and configure it with the Linux kernel module.

But When I make OpenVswitch, there is an error when building the datapath kernel module.

Here is the full log.

---

```
odroid@odroid:~/Downloads/openvswitch-2.15.4$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/odroid/Downloads/openvswitch-2.15.4'
Making all in datapath
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/odroid/Downloads/openvswitch-2.15.4/datapath'
Making all in linux
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/odroid/Downloads/openvswitch-2.15.4/datapath/linux'
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.167+/build  M=/home/odroid/Downloads/openvswitch-2.15.4/datapath/linux modules
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/odroid/linux'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 6 modules
ERROR: "geneve_dev_create_fb" [/home/odroid/Downloads/openvswitch-2.15.4/datapath/linux/vport-geneve.ko] undefined!
make[5]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:94: __modpost] Error 1
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1650: modules] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/odroid/linux'
make[3]: *** [Makefile.main:71: default] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/odroid/Downloads/openvswitch-2.15.4/datapath/linux'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:579: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/odroid/Downloads/openvswitch-2.15.4/datapath'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:5251: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/odroid/Downloads/openvswitch-2.15.4'
make: *** [Makefile:2996: all] Error 2
```

Comment: And I don't want using upstream tunnel in ovs